# After downloading the excel file using php it is giving error

Tags: php, excel

I have made a file downloader here i am downloading the excel file it downloads successfully but when i open the file it gives me the error mention below 
 Excel cannot open the file because the file format or file extension is not valid what is worng going on here

```
<?php

   if (isset($_POST['file_name'])) {

      $file_name = $_POST['file_name'];

      header('Content-type: application/octet-stream');
      header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$file_name.'"');
     readfile('mystery_folder/'.$file_name);
    exit();
  }

 ?>

<form action="indexa.php" method="post" name="downloadform">

 <input name="file_name" value="My Tracker.xlsx" size="50" type="text">
<input type="submit" value="Download">

</form>
```

Comment: be aware: `file_name=../../../etc/passwd` is bad.

Comment: I have tried that but still the same result

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to use a space in the filename:

```
value="My Tracker.xlsx"
```

It's probably not actually downloading the file, for lack of being able to find it.  You should rename the file without the space.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that is the correct filename (case sensitive)?  Are you also absolutely sure that your server is allowed to serve up XLSX files?  I'm not sure about this, but XLS is the preferred format for web download.  You may have to save your file as the older version and try it that way.

Comment: well i am trying this on my localhost

Comment: localhost can be anything.  Whatever server environment you're using be it Apache, IIS, or something that's part of a framework like Visual Studio or Zend, you still need to configure it.

Comment: Apache in WAMPSERVER

Answer (score 0):

Try to change Content-type:

```
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
```

and add:

```
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
```

This sample worked for me:

```
$file = 'sample.xlsx';
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
readfile(sprintf('./%s', $file));
```

Comment: I have changed this (application/octet-stream) but still the same problem

Comment: sorry bro after opening the file it still gives the error that the file format and file extension is not valid

Comment: probably your file was corrupted, when you upload it.
i checked code on this file: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0ahUKEwi4yqrb2InQAhVF2ywKHQXBAOkQFgglMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdev-builds.libreoffice.org%2Ftmp%2Ftest.xlsx&usg=AFQjCNFfr54yqm32uhf2WB5K03hSmTThcw&bvm=bv.137132246,d.bGg

can you check md5sum on each step

Comment: Better yet - change the extension to .zip and open that.  An XLSX file is just a packed archive.  If you can open it that way, you'll know the file is intact.  If not, it's hosed.